# page based application overload memory ARC don´t release pages

Tags: ios, swift

may you can help me with this memory issue. So I builded a app based on the project preset "Page-Based Application" everything works well, but over time the single views load every Viewcontroller into the physical memory and don´t release them. If the memory is full the app will crash.

here ist my code:

The RootViewController (CatalougeViewController):

```
import UIKit

class CatalougeViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    var pageViewController: UIPageViewController?
    var zoomTransform: CGAffineTransform?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        // Configure the page view controller and add it as a child view controller.
        self.pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .PageCurl, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: nil)
        self.pageViewController!.delegate = self

        let startingViewController: DataViewController = self.modelController.viewControllerAtIndex(0, storyboard: self.storyboard!)!
        let viewControllers = [startingViewController]
        self.pageViewController!.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: {done in })

        self.pageViewController!.dataSource = self.modelController

        self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController!)
        self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController!.view)


        // Set the page view controller's bounds using an inset rect so that self's view is visible around the edges of the pages.
        var pageViewRect = self.view.bounds
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
            pageViewRect = CGRectInset(pageViewRect, 0.0, 0.0)
        }
        self.pageViewController!.view.frame = pageViewRect
        self.pageViewController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        /*
        // Add the page view controller's gesture recognizers to the book view controller's view so that the gestures are started more easily.
        self.view.gestureRecognizers = self.pageViewController!.gestureRecognizers
        */

        self.view.gestureRecognizers = self.pageViewController?.gestureRecognizers


        let pinchRecognizer = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "pinchDetected:")
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(pinchRecognizer)

        let panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePan:")
        panRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2
        panRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2

        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer)
    }

    func pinchDetected(pinchRecognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

        if (UIGestureRecognizerState.Began == pinchRecognizer.state) || (UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed == pinchRecognizer.state) {


            // Use the x or y scale, they should be the same for typical zooming (non-skewing)
            let curScale = pinchRecognizer.view!.layer.valueForKeyPath("transform.scale.x")!.floatValue
            let currentScale = CGFloat(curScale!)

            // Variables to adjust the max/min values of zoom
            let minScale: CGFloat = 1.0;
            let maxScale: CGFloat = 2.0;
            let zoomSpeed: CGFloat = 0.5;

            var deltaScale: CGFloat = pinchRecognizer.scale

            // You need to translate the zoom to 0 (origin) so that you
            // can multiply a speed factor and then translate back to "zoomSpace" around 1
            deltaScale = ((deltaScale - 1) * zoomSpeed) + 1

            // Limit to min/max size (i.e maxScale = 2, current scale = 2, 2/2 = 1.0)
            //  A deltaScale is ~0.99 for decreasing or ~1.01 for increasing
            //  A deltaScale of 1.0 will maintain the zoom size
            deltaScale = min(deltaScale, maxScale / currentScale)
            deltaScale = max(deltaScale, minScale / currentScale)

            zoomTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(pinchRecognizer.view!.transform, deltaScale, deltaScale);
            pinchRecognizer.view!.transform = zoomTransform!;

            // Reset to 1 for scale delta's
            //  Note: not 0, or we won't see a size: 0 * width = 0
            pinchRecognizer.scale = 1;

        }

    }

    func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
        if let view = recognizer.view {
            view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                y:view.center.y + translation.y)
        }
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)



        if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
            // 1
            let velocity = recognizer.velocityInView(self.view)
            let magnitude = sqrt((velocity.x * velocity.x) + (velocity.y * velocity.y))
            let slideMultiplier = magnitude / 200
            // print("magnitude: \(magnitude), slideMultiplier: \(slideMultiplier)")

            // 2
            let slideFactor = 0.1 * slideMultiplier     //Increase for more of a slide
            // 3
            var finalPoint = CGPoint(x:recognizer.view!.center.x + (velocity.x * slideFactor),
                y:recognizer.view!.center.y + (velocity.y * slideFactor))
            // 4
            finalPoint.x = min(max(finalPoint.x, 0), self.view.bounds.size.width)
            finalPoint.y = min(max(finalPoint.y, 0), self.view.bounds.size.height)

            // 5
            UIView.animateWithDuration(Double(slideFactor),
                delay: 0,
                // 6
                options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut,
                animations: {recognizer.view!.center = finalPoint },
                completion: nil)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    var modelController: CatalougeViewControllerModel {
        // Return the model controller object, creating it if necessary.
        // In more complex implementations, the model controller may be passed to the view controller.
        if _modelController == nil {
            _modelController = CatalougeViewControllerModel()
        }
        return _modelController!
    }

    var _modelController: CatalougeViewControllerModel? = nil

    // MARK: - UIPageViewController delegate methods

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) -> UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation {
        if (orientation == .Portrait) || (orientation == .PortraitUpsideDown) || (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone) {
            // In portrait orientation or on iPhone: Set the spine position to "min" and the page view controller's view controllers array to contain just one view controller. Setting the spine position to 'UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid' in landscape orientation sets the doubleSided property to true, so set it to false here.
            let currentViewController = self.pageViewController!.viewControllers![0]
            let viewControllers = [currentViewController]
            self.pageViewController!.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: {done in })

            self.pageViewController!.doubleSided = false
            return .Min
        }

        // In landscape orientation: Set set the spine location to "mid" and the page view controller's view controllers array to contain two view controllers. If the current page is even, set it to contain the current and next view controllers; if it is odd, set the array to contain the previous and current view controllers.
        let currentViewController = self.pageViewController!.viewControllers![0] as! DataViewController
        var viewControllers: [UIViewController]

        let indexOfCurrentViewController = self.modelController.indexOfViewController(currentViewController)
        if (indexOfCurrentViewController == 0) || (indexOfCurrentViewController % 2 == 0) {
            let nextViewController = self.modelController.pageViewController(self.pageViewController!, viewControllerAfterViewController: currentViewController)
            viewControllers = [currentViewController, nextViewController!]
        } else {
            let previousViewController = self.modelController.pageViewController(self.pageViewController!, viewControllerBeforeViewController: currentViewController)
            viewControllers = [previousViewController!, currentViewController]
        }
        self.pageViewController!.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: {done in })

        return .Mid
    }

}
```

Thats the ViewControllerModel (CatalougeViewControllerModel):

```
class CatalougeViewControllerModel: NSObject, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int, storyboard: UIStoryboard) -> DataViewController? {
        // Return the data view controller for the given index.
        if (PDF3.imagePath.count == 0) || (index >= PDF3.imagePath.count) {
            return nil
        }

        // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
        let dataViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DataViewController") as! DataViewController
        dataViewController.dataObject = PDF3.imagePath[index]
        return dataViewController
    }

    func indexOfViewController(viewController: DataViewController) -> Int {
        // Return the index of the given data view controller.
        // For simplicity, this implementation uses a static array of model objects and the view controller stores the model object; you can therefore use the model object to identify the index.
        return PDF3.imagePath.indexOf(viewController.dataObject!) ?? NSNotFound
    }

    // MARK: - Page View Controller Data Source Seiten werden hochgezählt

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        var index = self.indexOfViewController(viewController as! DataViewController)
        if (index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound) {
            return nil
        }

        index--
        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index, storyboard: viewController.storyboard!)
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        var index = self.indexOfViewController(viewController as! DataViewController)
        if index == NSNotFound {
            return nil
        }

        index++
        if index == PDF3.imagePath.count {
            return nil
        }
        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index, storyboard: viewController.storyboard!)
    }

}
```

Thank you for your time to help me...

Comment: You most likely have a retain cycle somewhere. Try using Instruments for help finding the place that is leaking. When you do, try using the `weak` variable to break the retain cycle.

Comment: nope it isn´t a memory leak. My cycle to convert pdf to UIImages is released with autorelease {}  this is not the problem. Instruments don´t show a leak. The Problem is that every page in the pageviewcontroller will load in the memory and after I open two or three pdf the memory is full, because every page loaded in the memory and will never released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem. So sorry guys the solution was in the DataViewController and I doesn´t posted my DataViewController file so anyway.

Here is my solution:

old DataViewController:

```
import UIKit

class DataViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!

    var dataObject: String?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

            self.myImageView.image = UIImage(named: dataObject!)
            // my Images was cached because I used "named:"


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}
```

Thats the new DataViewController:

```
import UIKit

class DataViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!

    var dataObject: String?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        autoreleasepool { () -> () in
            self.myImageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: dataObject!) // with "contentsOfFile:" the images are uncached...
        }


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

There exists a method on iOS that gets called whenever a device's memory gets constrained. By default, only the `UIApplicationDelegate`'s gets called, but you can use `NSNotificationCenter` to add any class and/or object so they also get called.

When the method is called, it's a signal for your app to free some memory. You can then purge data that you don't need anymore.

Comment: that sounds good to me, which is the name of this method. I fixed my problem 5 minutes ago but your trick is very interesting.

Comment: `applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:` Additional documentation should be in `UIApplicationDelegate`'s protocol reference.